# EmberJS Model Array

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is there any way to define arrays on EmberJS models? I saw some posts using Transformation but those approaches don't achieve the results I need.

This is the (json) model I'm trying to represent:

```
{
    "category" : "Category 1",
    "subcategories" : [
        {
            "name" : "subcategory1",
            "value" : 210
        },
        {
            "name" : "subcategory2",
            "value" : 220
        }
    ]
},
{
    "category" : "Category 2",
    "subcategories" : [
        {
            "name" : "subcategory21",
            "value" : 250
        },
        {
            "name" : "subcategory22",
            "value" : 270
        }
    ]
}
```

I read about the `hasMany` method but I understand that it's only for relationships. If so, how can I represent that example json as ember model?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

For those that are having the same doubt/issue:

http://thejsguy.com/2016/01/29/working-with-nested-data-in-ember-data-models.html

Comment: Instead of posting link as an answer, you can post the answer you derived from this link for your question. that would be useful to others.